# Is there a version of NPOI that works with ASP.NET Core 1.1 (not core 2.0)

Tags: asp.net-core, npoi

Is there a version of NPOI that works with **ASP.NET Core 1.1** (not core 2.0). Every package is either for the **Windows** version or **Core 2.0**, which, in both cases, is not working with **Core 1.1**.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely not. The library is probably depending on .NET Standard 2.0 for .NET Core support. The earliest version of .NET Core to be cross-targetable is 2.0. For what it's worth, there's really zero reason to still be on .NET Core 1.1. It's not that big of a deal to upgrade, and honestly .NET Core 1.1 was not really viable for production use.

Comment: I agree. I'm struggling to add features as I can't technologies, such as DataSet and DataAdapter either. We're upgrading soon to core 2.0.

Comment: Might as well go all the way to 2.1, or even 2.2 if it's released by then. Both add important features missing from 2.0, and as long as you're upgrading anyways...